# The most lazy way to call the vim-copied content into bash

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste

Setting in my `.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Supporting in my vim:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
```

I want to copy content in vim to be called by bash.

```
vim test.sh
echo "it is a test"
```

Enter into `vim's` command mode,`1y`,then move cursor to my bash terminal. If I press middle key in mouse, nothing shown in the terminal, in order to get the content to be used by bash, there are two ways:

1. I have to press right key in mouse and select `paste`.
2. Issue the command in vim--`1y*` and press middle key in bash.

Can I set some configuration in `.vimrc` to achieve my target -- `1y` in vim and middle key the mouse in bash?

Comment: Your `vimrc` has no effect on bash. You didn't mention which terminal emulator you're using, but pasting from the clipboard into the shell is often accomplished by ctrl-shift-v.

Comment: Have you tried with `clipboard=unnamed`?